# AWS EKS CLI command - if/else not working

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, aws-cli, amazon-eks

I'm trying to do a basic if/else that checks to see if a cluster already exists before creating another of that name. This is the entire section;

```
 cluster=$(aws eks list-clusters | jq -r ".clusters" | grep mycluster_test)
 
 if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
     echo "this worked, the cluster is $cluster"
 else
     echo "no cluster by this name"
 fi
```

There is no cluster with this name, and when I run the script it returns nothing. But I don't understand why it's not returning the else statement

I do have a cluster called 'mycluster_new' and when I `grep` for this, the first echo statement is returned, so can I please get help on why the `else` statement is failing. Thanks

Comment: Not sure about the exit status but you can test if the variable is emtpy or not. `if [[ -n "$cluster" ]]; then ...; else ...; fi`

Comment: Did my solution worked for you?

Comment: Hi Jatin, I actually managed to get it resolved. Will answer my question now. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Managed to resolve this by checking if the string was empty and ran a check that would continue regardless of if it was empty or not.

```
CLUSTER=my_eks_cluster

CHECK_NAME=$(aws eks list-clusters | jq -r ".clusters" | grep $CLUSTER || true)
```

then ran a check for this;

```
    if [ "$CHECK_NAME" != "" ]; then
        echo "There is already a cluster by this name; $CHECK_NAME. Cannot build another"
        exit 1
    else
        echo "No cluster by this name $CLUSTER, will continue with terraform"
    fi
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

if your vairabe is string

```
if [[ $cluster == 1 ]]; then
```

if your variable is integer

```
if [[ $cluster -eq 1 ]]; then
```

Answer (score 0):

if you really want to go ahead with your old way, you can always use '-z' to check if the string is null

```
 if [ -z "$cluster" ]; then
     echo "this worked, the cluster is $cluster"
 else
     echo "no cluster by this name"
 fi
```